# Get GPS from iPhone to wifi iPad via bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to transmit GPS data from a GPS-enabled iPhone to a wifi-only iPad? Does anyone have sample code to share that would do this?

How about getting GPS data from an Android via bluetooth, over to a wifi iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you would need to create an application for both devices that would communicate with each other. You cannot get the location over wifi without a custom application sending the data.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the WiTap sample app. This app allows two devices to find each other and send data to each other using WiFi. You can adapt this code so one device sends location data it obtains to the other device instead of info about which rectangle was tapped.

I have no info for doing this with Android.